# Eigenvectors of a large Graph

Tags: algebraic-graph-theory

Please i am working on a graph with a huge number of vertices, and i have a particular eigenvalue having and eigen space of dimension 19, What is the best way to find the eigen vectors.
Here is what i have done: I have already used the matrix B and i got an eigen vector which i extend to an eigen vector of the adjacency matrix A using the Px formula where x is an eigen vector for B and P is the characteristic matrix of the distance partitions (Using the reasoning of equitable partitions). But ow can i more generally get a basis for the eigen space?

Comment: How is your graph represented? or how it is given? what is $B$?

Comment: Its actually a strong regular graph given in terms of the parameters with 72 vertices, so i am actually avoiding drawing the graph though. The matrix B is the (d+1)x(d+1) matrix which is formed from the parameters of a distance regular graph. The aim is to use the vector representation though.

Comment: There exists a strongly regular graph on 72 vertices?? What are its parameters?

Comment: The graph actually doesn't exist, my task is to prove the nonexistence. I want to use this as an exercise because the number of vertices is relative small compared to the graph i would actually be working on. But i am stock trying to find the most efficient method to determine the eigen vector. Or do i necessarily have to go through the Adjacency matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, 72 is a *small* number of vertices. Second, a strongly regular graph on $p+1$ vertices (where $p$ is prime) is either the disjoint union of complete graphs, or is the complement of such a graph.

Comment: Professor Chris Godsil i would like to kindly mention that the method i described above was an idea i was able to derive from your book on Algebraic combinatorics sir. But my problem lies in finding the eigen vectors for the representation. To find the eigen vectors is it the best approach to go through the whole adjacency matrix. I used the Matrix P, but Px only gives me one vector in an eigen space of 19.

Comment: If you have the parameters for the erg, you can write down the spectral idempotents $E_r$ ($r=0,1,2$) immediately, the columns of these matrices are eigenvectors for their respective eigenspaces - in fact they span.

Comment: Thank you very much for this kind hint. This is the perfect hint i needed..